What does N stand for in C.ADDI4SPN?
I would like to know what "N" stands for in the mnemonic C.ADDI4SPN in RVC.
This mnemonic is very similar to C.ADDI16SP. There are two differences between these instructions. The first is that the lower 2 bits of the immediate value in C.ADDI4SPN are 0 compared to the lower 4 for C.ADDI16SP; this is obviously captured by the "16" and "4" in the mnemonics. The other difference is that the result is saved to rd' rather sp, so this must be what the "N" refers to. My best guess is that it gets the address of the Nth word on the stack.
Edit: A third difference is that the immediate is unsigned for C.ADDI4SPN.
As an aside, why does the manual say that C.ADDI16SP expands to addi x2, x2, nzimm[9:4] rather than addi x2, x2, nzimm? Only immediates that are multiples of 16 in the range (-512,496) are encodable and this is the approach taken, e.g., for C.LWSP.

Related: How to use C.ADDI4SPN and C.ADDI16SP instructions (compressed subset) of RISC-V architecture? shows equivalent non-compressed instructions, and that c.addi4spn a0, sp, 8 assembles to the same machine code as addi a0, sp, 8.  So the n isn't negating or anything.  I wonder if it might be "new destination" as opposed to the other which implicitly writes SP, but that doesn't seem like a great guess.

@PeterCordes I agree - "new destination" is the closest thing to looking like a somewhat consistent meaning given that c.addi16sp doesn't have an n. It would be lovely to hear an answer from the original designer though!

Another search highlighted The RISC-V Reader, which has a brief suggestion of something I hadn't considered: https://www.cs.sfu.ca/~ashriram/Courses/CS295/assets/books/rvbook.pdf
"Non-destructive"
This would make a lot of sense, as ADDI4SPN doesn't destroy the current stack pointer, whereas ADDI16SP does.
